# regex or sth to pull parts of the table from web page to spreadsheet with google apps script

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, html-table, fetch, spreadsheet

I need to pull everyday data from web page for statistical analysis

Webpage is:
http://sagarin.com/sports/nbasend.htm

Desired part:
[image]

What is the best way to pull the table at the end of the web page from the row beneath "===" to row above "EIGENVECTOR" part?
And is it possible to pull that data to separate 9 columns in spreadsheet?

When I look at the page source code I see that the parts of that table are not closed by proper tags and that the whole table is one entity and I think that is a problem.

Source code:
[image]

I need a example of regex to pull that and I will adjust it. For now that regex part is big question mark for me?

```
function pullNBA() {

var page = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://sagarin.com/sports/nbasend.htm").getContentText();

  var number = page.match(??/m)[1];

  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('NBA').appendRow([new Date(), number]);

}
```

Comment: Sorry, I had a spare `)` in my answer below, jsut fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

### No need to use regex

It is probably more intuitive to use [split()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) which can solve your issue just as well.

How does it work?

- You define a separator
- The string will be divided in two parts - left and right from the separator, while the separator itself will be dropped
- You can chose with [0] or [1] either you want the left or right substring

In your case:

```
function pullNBA() {
var page = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://sagarin.com/sports/nbasend.htm").getContentText();
page = page.split("======================================================================================================")[1];
var number = page.split("EIGENVECTOR")[0];  
}
```

Comment: Thank you @ziganotschka
But when I use split function to pull data to spreadsheet with this line after your code:
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('NBA').appendRow([new Date(), number]);
I get all rows from webpage in only one row in spreadsheet. Is it possible to get every row from webpage to different row of spreadsheet?

Comment: Yes, for this you can split by '\n' (line break): `var row0 = number.split("\n")[0]; var row1 = number.split("\n")[1]...`. Preferably in a loop iterating until `number.split("\n").length`.